# How do I reduce the number of attempts in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, math

I'm creating a game where you guess a point and if you guess correctly you win, however if you guess incorrectly you're attempts go down. There's only one problem though. The attempts won't go down. I'm not good at wording questions sorry.

I have tried to change the if statements, I have tried to change the -= sign to just a - sign which kind of worked except for the fact that once it loops it goes back to the original number it was before the attempts - 1 function.

```
while True:
    attempts = 5
    print(attempts)
    x = input("Guess the X coordinate.")
    y = input("Guess the Y coordinate.")

    a = random.randrange(100)
    b = random.randrange(100)

    p = Point(a,b)

    print(p)

    if x and y == a and b:
        print("Yay you did it; you found both coordinates.")
    elif x == a:
        print("You only found the X coordinate.")
    elif x == b:
        print("You only found the Y coordinate")
    else:
        print("you disgust me.")
        print(attempts - 1)

    while attempts < 5:

        if attempts > 1:
            print('you can play again')
            continue
        else:
            print('you lost')
            exit()
```

Comment: You didn't ask about this, but change `if x and y == a and b` to `if x==a and y == b`. What you have now is checking for something different from what I'm pretty sure you want. Namely, it is checking that `x` is not zero, `y` is equal to `a`, and that `b` is not zero.

Comment: Also, change `x = input(...)` and `y = input(...)` to `x = int(input(...))` and `y = int(input(...))` respectively. Otherwise, you'll be comparing `str`s to `int`s, because `input` returns a `str`. (Assuming you are actually using Python3 as indicated by your tags)

Comment: mypetlion I made so that it one of the if statements checked for both of the x and y values being equal to the a and b values. The other if statements check to see if the x value is equal to a and the y value is equal to b separately but not at the same time. So if you had (9,3) and the answer was (9,7) then it would check to see if the x value was equal to the a value.

Comment: my petlion that does absolutely nothing because I have defined a certain type of string in my Point class it looks like this. __str__ . It makes it so that the a and b values end up as a string. the x and y values will always stay as an integer no matter what.

Comment: imagine 2 underscores on either side of the str

Comment: With the `x and y == a and b` statement, I understand that what you've described is what you're trying to do, but I'm saying that that's not what that statement is actually testing for. `x and y == a and b` does not check that x is equal to a and y is equal to b. It checks that x is not zero, then it checks that y is equal to a, then it checks that b is not zero. You've got the syntax wrong for what you've just described in your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `attempts += -1`:

```
attempts = 5
while attempts > 0:
    print(attempts)
    x = input("Guess the X coordinate.")
    y = input("Guess the Y coordinate.")
    a = random.randrange(100)
    b = random.randrange(100)

    p = Point(a,b)

    print(p)

    if x and y == a and b:
        print("Yay you did it; you found both coordinates.")
    elif x == a:
        print("You only found the X coordinate.")
    elif x == b:
        print("You only found the Y coordinate")
    else:
        print("you disgust me.")
        attempts += -1
        print(attempts)

    if attempts > 0:
        print('you can play again')
        continue
    else:
        print('you lost')
        exit()
```

Comment: This won't work, you have indentation problems and the loop at the end will keep the program stuck forever

Comment: it got it it to go down but it still loops should I make it it's own loop away from the other loop I have ?